# Liferay 7 with MySQL Server 5.6 not starting

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, liferay, liferay-7

I’d just downloaded latest **Liferay 7 Tomcat bundle**

> liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.0-ga3-20160804222206210

Extracted it and stared from liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3\tomcat-8.0.32\bin\startup.bat. Server started successfully and first screen opened on browser. Then I provided basic configurations and database (**MySQL Server 5.6**) details etc. and re-stared server as instructed. But now whenever I’m starting the server, throwing following exception and server is not starting. Can anyone help me to identify the issue please?

```
10:23:40,085 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:501] Database does not support case sensitive queries
You must first upgrade to Liferay Portal 7002
10:23:40,097 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][MainServlet:237] java.lang.RuntimeException: You must first upgrade to Liferay Portal 7002
java.lang.RuntimeException: You must first upgrade to Liferay Portal 7002
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.checkRequiredBuildNumber(DBUpgrader.java:86)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:190)
    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:85)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1290)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:234)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Stopping the server due to unexpected startup errors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have pointed Liferay to a database with existing data. In that case you'll have to run the upgrade routines before starting Liferay. This is a separate tool starting with version 7.0 - it used to be bundled within the server in prior versions. The documentation should contain all required information.

Answering your comment: The line

```
10:23:40,097 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][MainServlet:237] java.lang.RuntimeException: 
You must first upgrade to Liferay Portal 7002
```

clearly indicates that Liferay found the tables and data structure from a previous version in the database that you're pointing to. Note that a `portal-ext.properties` file will also be picked up if it's in the current user's home directory - that might override the settings that you expect to set in the installation's private `portal-ext.properties` or `portal-setup-wizard.properties`.

In addition, I do recommend to explicitly use a mysql-driver version matching your mysql-server version. Otherwise Liferay will download a driver from the maven repositories and it might not match 100%. I've seen problems arise from that.

Comment: I'm not using existing database. I'd just created a fresh database in MySQL server. All Liferay documents are guiding upgrade from 6.* to 7. But here I already downloaded latest one i.e. 7.0. Then what I have to upgrade again?

Comment: Thank you very much Olaf. I just verified portal-setup-wizard.properties where default database name was mentioned lportal while I'd created database with different name and unfortunately lportal was having data of old portal 6.2. I'd corrected it and now it's working fine. You got it right. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
10:23:40,085 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:501] Database does not support case sensitive queries You must first upgrade to Liferay Portal 7002
```

Did you tried this previous advise from your stacktrace ?